# App UI builder in Visual Studio Android Development doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have recently installed Visual Studio with Xamarin to basically make android apps in c#, but I have run into a problem.
When I try to build the application, the window that shows is different to the designer window:
[-> The Windows <-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1O0Y.png)

Main.axml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace RemindMe
{
    [Activity(Label = "RemindMe", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, "Welcome! This app is currently under construction...", ToastLength.Short).Show();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your Visible property is false, please post your code to find more information.

Comment: The axml file? - its literally just a button.

Comment: There - updated it. Theres not much though

Comment: In the mainactivity.cs file?

Comment: Yes, this sentence. // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);  Delete the "//'.

Comment: If this work for you, please check it as an answer. : )

Comment: I will do - when i get home, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use  `SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main)`, this method set the activity content from a layout resource.[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is the document.